# ¿Como puedo acceder desde el pc a ficheros en android?

Tags: java, android-studio, usb

Quiero hacer una aplicación como ApowerManager o Moborobo. Una aplicacion para PC con la que pueda conectarme a mi movil pero desde el cable usb, no por internet o conexión de otro tipo, solo por cable USB y transferencia de archivos.

Quiero poder acceder a ficheros que estan en la memoria del telefono desde el PC.

Estoy buscando por internet y no encuentro o no se buscar la información para hacer este tipo de conexiones. Todo lo que encuentro es para hacerlo por WIFI o similares.

[Encontre información sobre conexión con Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417442/client-server-file-transfer-from-android-to-pc-connected-via-socket)
Pero creo que simpre es por conexion TCP. Cuando hago pruebas me da error de `Network is unreachable` Porque creo que necesita algun tipo de conexión.
Quizas hay alguna forma para que por usb se conecte via IP. Pero lo desconozco.

Si me podeis ayudar y pasar algun link o algun dato que me pueda orientar. Yo trabajo con JAVA pero con Kotlin me entiendo, el tema es buscar la idea y la tecnica para poder resolver este problema.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: hola checa esto es posible que es lo que estas buscando
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jmtp/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645275/desktop-java-app-copy-and-transfer-android-data-via-usb/29768435#29768435

Answer (score 0):

Debe activar el modo desarrollador para eso ve a `ajustes/acerca del teléfono/número de compilación` y luego pulsa muchas veces hasta que te salga modo desarrollador.

Y dentro de esos ajustes activa la depuración por USB y solucionado

Ve a **`Menú > Ajustes > Acerca del dispositivo`**

Sigue tocando Número de compilación 4 a 8 veces

Vuelve a la página **`Ajustes > Desbloquee Opciones del desarrollador > Elija Depuración USB`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]